# How to add a startup script to a mysql docker container?

Tags: mysql, sql, docker

I started a docker container with mysql.
Actually i want to create a new user and a new table - and i have to do it in the MySQL Workbench.

This ist my docker run command:
`docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mysql-server -v ~/Development/web/myproject/docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:latest`

My Question is:
How can i add a sql startup script (only for the first start of the container) which creates my user and my table?
Which steps do i have to do?

Could some one help me here?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to create user via `MYSQL_USER`, `MYSQL_PASSWORD` env vars and use volume `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` to map directory with your startup scripts (`.sh`, `.sql`, `.sql.gz`)

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mysql-server \ 
 -v ~/Development/web/myproject/docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
 -v ~/Development/web/myproject/docker/yourstartupscripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d \
 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root \
 -e MYSQL_USER=youruser \
 -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=youruserpassword \
 -d mysql:latest
```

Explanation from: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

**MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD**
These variables are optional, used in conjunction to create a new user and to set that user's password. This user will be granted superuser permissions (see above) for the database specified by the `MYSQL_DATABASE` variable. Both variables are required for a user to be created.

**Initializing a fresh instance**
When a container is started for the first time, a new database with the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with extensions `.sh`, `.sql` and `.sql.gz` that are found in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Files will be executed in alphabetical order. You can easily populate your mysql services by [mounting a SQL dump into that directory](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-file-as-a-data-volume) and provide [custom images](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/) with contributed data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified by the `MYSQL_DATABASE` variable.

Comment: thank you `-v ~/Development/web/myproject/docker/yourstartupscripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` -> that was it what i searched for :)

Comment: what is the difference by creating a new user by script or creating it in the docker run command?

Comment: @m1well you can check out exactly how user is created here: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/0590e4efd2b31ec794383f084d419dea9bc752c4/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh#L166-L174

Comment: ah ok - so it is the same way like i do it in my script. then i prefer my script :) -- thank you!

Comment: On any subsequent docker startups the scripts will not be executed right ?